# How to count tweets number of 2 hashtags and display which one is more mentioned

Tags: twitter, arduino, processing, hashtag, tweets

Good day
me and my team are new to coding languages, we are trying through multiple methods to make an arduino based indicator that shows which keyword out of two is more mentioned during the last 5 minutes on twitter

we tried using adafruit + IFTTT and we managed to have a stream of real time tweets of two hashtags but we are trying to find a way to collect that info and make a code that compare the total number of both hashtags and send command to arduino to spine the servo motor based on the result.

and then we tried to do it through processing language and we found this code that makes displays related hashtag tweets on screen but we couldn't make it search for two words and compare the numbers and then send signal to arduino :

```
    //http://codasign.com/tutorials/processing-and-twitter

import twitter4j.conf.*;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.auth.*;
import twitter4j.api.*;
import java.util.*;

Twitter twitter;
String searchString = "#poznan";

List<Status> tweets;

int currentTweet;

void setup()
{
  size(800, 600);

  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("");
  cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("");
  cb.setOAuthAccessToken("");
  cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");

  TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());

  twitter = tf.getInstance();

  getNewTweets();

  currentTweet = 1;

  thread("refreshTweets");
}

void draw()
{
  fill(0, 40);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);

  currentTweet = currentTweet + 1;

  if (currentTweet >= tweets.size())
  {
    currentTweet = 0;
  }

  Status status = tweets.get(currentTweet);

  fill(200);
  text(status.getText(), random(width), random(height), 300, 200);

  delay(250);
}

void getNewTweets()
{
  try
  {
    Query query = new Query(searchString);
    //query.setSince("2016-03-17");
    //query.setCount(100);
    query.setResultType(Query.RECENT);
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

    tweets = result.getTweets();
    println(tweets.size());
  }
  catch (TwitterException te)
  {
    System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
    System.exit(-1);
  }
}

void refreshTweets()
{
  while (true)
  {
    getNewTweets();

    println("Updated Tweets");

    delay(60000);
  }
}
```

We are looking for alternative codes and methods to make our concept work
we are open to suggestions, don't hesitate to write to us.

Comment: Stack Overflow really isn't designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. You need to break your problem down into smaller pieces: can you create a small example sketch that simply retrieves tweets that contain a certain hashtag? Start with that, and post a [mcve] if you get stuck. Trying to hammer code you found on the internet and don't really understand will just lead to more headaches. Use that code as a way to understand what's going on, and then write your own code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably split this problem in smaller ones.

A. How do I connect to Twitter and "listen" to two hashtags, counting them and comparing them.

B. How do I use arduino to move a servo according to some arbitary number in a specific range.

C. How do I communicate a number between Arduino and processing, via desired channel (wi-fi? bluetooth? usb?)

Of course this can be break even further, and perhaps it should.

Doing like this is going to be much easier to develop and debug your code. Once you got all that figured out, start to combine them.

For `B` and `C` I can help very little, it's been sometime since I last touched my Arduino. But those are not really hard to be done. In [the Processing forum](https://forum.processing.org/two/) you can find a lot of answers about serial communication with Arduino. The search of the forum is not so good. But you can always use Google. Something like: `serial arduino site:processing.org` will do the search in all forums (this is like the third version) and give you easier to navigate results.

For `A`, I'd suggest you try a "stream" from Twitter's [streamingAPI](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview). Once you start getting results, just add them to different `List`s, like

`hashtag1` and `hashtag2`.

The size of each list is what you are looking for (if I get this right)

`hashtag1.size() - hashtag2.size()` will give you the "balance" between them.

**edit:** If, you are not going to need those status you can just add to two ints... (h1++, h2++), and forget the lists.

Here some stream sample code to get you started:

```java
import twitter4j.util.*;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.management.*;
import twitter4j.api.*;
import twitter4j.conf.*;
import twitter4j.json.*;
import twitter4j.auth.*;


TwitterStream twitterStream;

// if you enter keywords here it will filter, otherwise it will sample
String keywords[] = {
//all you need is...
  "love"
};



void setup() {     
  size(100, 100);    
  background(0); 
  openTwitterStream();
}  


void draw() {     
  background(0);
}  


// Stream it
void openTwitterStream() {  

  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();  

  //fill oAuth data below
  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("");
  cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("");
  cb.setOAuthAccessToken("");
  cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(""); 
  cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
  cb.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
  twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

  FilterQuery filtered = new FilterQuery();



  filtered.track(keywords);

  twitterStream.addListener(listener);

  if (keywords.length==0) {
    // sample() method internally creates a thread which manipulates TwitterStream 
    // and calls these adequate listener methods continuously. With a sample of the fireRose
    twitterStream.sample(); 
  } else { 
    twitterStream.filter(filtered);
  }
  println("connecting...");
} 


// Implementing StatusListener interface
StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

  //@Override
  public void onStatus(Status status) {
    System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
  }

  //@Override
  public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
    System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
  }

  //@Override
  public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
    System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
  }

  //@Override
  public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
    System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
  }

  //@Override
  public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
    System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
  }

  //@Override
  public void onException(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
};
```

Comment: Alright, thank you everyone for your time, we got it all figured out.